# Option for displaying data in real time in Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, asp.net-mvc, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm currently looking for alternatives that can provide a Xamarin-app with real time data. Today I have an app that gets data pushed to a server via NServiceBus, and then it's published, again with NServiceBus, to my html-app which in turn updates the view using SignalR (All developed with Asp.net mvc and KendoUI). Being a .net developer, I don't really fancy javascript and html for apps and would like to move to Xamarin and something more close to native when developing apps for iOS and Android.

Does anyone know of a decent tutorial / post / read on the subject? Any experience with the same kind of structure?

Comment: There is SignalR for the Xamarin platforms: http://www.gregshackles.com/2013/04/updates-on-my-signalr-fork-and-xamarin-support/

Comment: Ah, thanks @Krumelur! Don't know how I could even miss the fact that they've added official support for it as well! Care to add an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my comment an answer: I think your best option is to stick with SignalR if you're already used to it. Official support for SignalR on Xamarin platforms was announced at Evolve 2013. You can find more information at [Greg Shackle's blog](http://www.gregshackles.com/2013/04/updates-on-my-signalr-fork-and-xamarin-support/) and there's a demo of SignalR on various platforms (including iOS and Android) at [Scott Hanselman's Github repo](https://github.com/shanselman/PanTiltZoomSystem).

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Just out of curiousity; do you know of any other alternatives for pushing real-time data to an app built with xamarin?

Comment: Only for iOS7 specifically. There are now silent push notifications.